# How to check payments and process new deposits

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc, payment-id, payment-integration, account, payment

Is there a method for checking payments within one account in addition to `get_bulk_payments`?

We have a lot of *payment_id* to check, and day by day the request is longer and longer.

Is there any method to avoid this and to get the incoming payments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [get_transfers](https://www.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#get_transfers). It has many options for filtering your transfers.